# Isolating scope for multiple d3 components in AngularJS directives within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I'm building a dynamic dashboard using ng-repeat and using D3 dials built using an AngularJS directive.

When I run 1 directive tag it works fine. When I have 2+ directive tags in the ng-repeat then it seems like a get some strange race condition where the directives are using the same variables. How do I guarantee that the directives instances have completely isolated scope?

It looks like I'm having problems isolating the progress variable. The 2 dials (directive instance) are interpolating the same progress value and getting messed up. I've tried moving the progress variable to different scopes within the directive but cannot find a solution.

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl" ng-init="init();">
<div ng-repeat="item in metrics">
  <div ng-switch on="item.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="dial">
        <gh-dial val="item.data" data-format="item.data-format" metric-title="item.title" gh-target="item.target"></gh-dial>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="meter">
        <gh-meter val="item.data" data-format="item.data-format" metric-title="item.title" gh-target="item.target"></gh-meter>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Directive:

```
directives.directive('ghDial', function () {

var width = 370,
    height = 370,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
    progress = 0;

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    val: '=',
  dataFormat: '=',
  metricTitle: '=',
  ghTarget: '='
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

  console.debug(scope.dataFormat);
   var formatPercent = d3.format(scope.dataFormat);
   var total = scope.ghTarget.valueOf() ;
   var prepend = "" ;
   if (scope.dataFormat === "$") scope.prepend = "$" ;
   console.debug("prepend: "+scope.prepend);
   console.debug("data format: "+scope.dataFormat );

  // set up initial svg object
var vis = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('fill', '#2E7AF9')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


  scope.$watch('val', function (newVal, oldVal) {


      vis.selectAll('*').remove();


        // if 'val' is undefined, exit
        if (!newVal) {
          return;
        }

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .startAngle(0)
            .innerRadius(140)
            .outerRadius(170)
        ;

        var meter = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "progress-meter");

        meter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "background")
            .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

        var foreground = meter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "foreground");

        var text = meter.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size","14px");

        var text2 = meter.append("text")
            .attr("y", 40)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "text2");

            console.debug(scope.metricTitle);
            text2.text(scope.metricTitle);

        var animate = function(percentage) {

            var i = d3.interpolate(progress, percentage/total);

            d3.transition().duration(800).tween("progress", function () {
                return function (t) {
                    progress = i(t);
                    foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
                    console.debug("progress:"+progress);
                    text.text(prepend+''+percentage);
                };
            });
        }; 

        setTimeout(function () {
        console.debug(newVal);
        animate(newVal.expr0.valueOf());
        }, 500);

  });
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. I think the main issue was add a D3 select() on the transition line so D3 knows which dial it is transitioning. I also pulled the append SVG out of the directive and just have one SVG in the document now. The directive is appending groups under the SVG tag. Looks awesome!

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl" ng-init="init();">
<svg id="d3Parent" width="1000" height="1000" fill="#2E7AF9">
</svg>
<div ng-repeat="item in metrics">
  <div ng-switch on="item.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="dial">
        <gh-dial val="item.data" data-format="item.data-format" metric-title="item.title" gh-target="item.target"></gh-dial>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="meter">
        <gh-meter val="item.data" data-format="item.data-format" metric-title="item.title" gh-target="item.target"></gh-meter>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
directives.directive('ghDial', function () {

var width = 370,
    height = 370,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
    progress = 0.00001;

return {
  restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
  scope: {
      val: '=',
  dataFormat: '=',
  metricTitle: '=',
  ghTarget: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

  console.debug(attrs['data-format']);
   var formatPercent = d3.format(scope.dataFormat);
   var total = scope.ghTarget.valueOf() ;
   var prepend = "" ;
   if (scope.dataFormat === "$") prepend = "$" ;
   console.debug("prepend: "+scope.prepend);
   console.debug("data format: "+scope.dataFormat );

   var index = document.querySelector("#d3Parent").childNodes.length-1 ;

   var column = [200, 600];
   var row = [200, 500, 750]

  // set up initial svg object
var vis = d3.select("#d3Parent")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + column[index%2] + "," + row[0] + ")");  

  scope.$watch('val', function (newVal, oldVal) {

      console.debug("directive watch fired:"+scope.metricTitle);

      vis.selectAll('*').remove();

        // if 'val' is undefined, exit
        if (!newVal) {
          return;
        }

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .startAngle(0)
            .innerRadius(140)
            .outerRadius(170)
        ;

        var meter = vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "progress-meter");

        meter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "background")
            .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

        var foreground = meter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "foreground");

        var text = meter.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size","24px");

        var text2 = meter.append("text")
            .attr("y", 40)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "text2");

            console.debug(scope.metricTitle);
            text2.text(scope.metricTitle);

        var percentage = newVal.expr0.valueOf() ;


            console.debug("animate progress: "+progress+" percentage:"+percentage+" total:"+total);
            var i = d3.interpolateNumber(progress, percentage/total);

            d3.select(vis).transition().duration(800).tween("progress", function () {
                return function (t) {
                    progress = i(t);
                    foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
                    console.debug("progress:"+progress);
                    text.text(prepend+''+percentage);
                };
            });



  });
}
}
});
```